# wpf Bind Listbox in Listview column subclass Object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a properties 'AllShobeh'

```
public struct listViewShobehItem
        {
            string _code;
            string _name;
            string _tell;
            string _address;
            List<string> _atms;

            public string Code
            {
                get
                {
                    return _code;
                }

                set
                {
                    _code = value;
                }
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return _name;
                }

                set
                {
                    _name = value;
                }
            }

            public string Tell
            {
                get
                {
                    return _tell;
                }

                set
                {
                    _tell = value;
                }
            }

            public string Address
            {
                get
                {
                    return _address;
                }

                set
                {
                    _address = value;
                }
            }

            public List<string> Atms
            {
                get
                {
                    return _atms;
                }

                set
                {
                    _atms = value;
                }
            }
        }

ObservableCollection<listViewShobehItem> _AllShobeh = new ObservableCollection<listViewShobehItem>();
public ObservableCollection<listViewShobehItem> AllShobeh
        {
            get { return _AllShobeh; }
            set
            {
                _AllShobeh = new ObservableCollection<listViewShobehItem>(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("AllShobeh");
            }
        }
```

My Code in constructor :

```
AllShobeh = new ObservableCollection<listViewShobehItem>(from a in STATICS.db.shobehs
                                                     select new listViewShobehItem() {Code = a.code,Name=a.name,Tell=a.tell,Address=a.address,Atms=(from at in STATICS.db.atms 
                                                                                                                                                    where at.shobehCode==a.code
                                                                                                                                                    select at.code + " - " + at.name).ToList()});
        listviewShobeh.DataContext = this;
        this.DataContext = this;
        listviewShobeh.ItemsSource = AllShobeh;
```

i want show `AllShobeh` in a listview and show `Atms` in last column of listView in Listbox ...

this is my Xaml Code :

```
<ListView Name="listviewShobeh" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colCode" Header="code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Code}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="tell" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tell}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Address}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="atms" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Expander>
                                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listviewShobeh,Path=Atms}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                                </Expander>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

i cant bind Allshobeh.Atms to listBox Atms column ...

[My Question In Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSWYJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete ElementName and DisplayMemberPath from your binding.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Expander>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Atms}" />
    </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

Also, more importantly, you're confused about DataContext and ViewModel class, let me know if you need specific help about this point.